# How can I get the Definition and Theorem environment like these in LaTeX package SVMono?

Tags: theorems, definition

How can I get the Definition and Theorem environment like these in  LaTeX package SVMono ?[image]

Comment: Hope all `Springer` macros are still maintaining by the `Springer Team`, better you can approach them...

Comment: Thanks. @ MadyYuvi

Comment: You can use the [`beaulivre`](https://ctan.org/pkg/beaulivre) package to get the theorem and definition environments as such. The fonts seem to be [`Kp-Fonts`](https://ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts-otf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used `TikZ` and declared a `newtheoremstyle` as detailed on page 9 of the [`amsthm`](http://linorg.usp.br/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) documentation. The `TikZ` creates the background and colors and the `newtheoremstyle` defines title, color of title, spacing after and before theorem text, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{amber}{rgb}{1.0, 0.49, 0.0}
\definecolor{cadmiumgreen}{rgb}{0.0, 0.42, 0.24}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newtheoremstyle{styleth}%
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below 
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries\color{amber}}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{styleth}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{styledef}%
{3pt}% Space above
{3pt}% Space below 
{}% Body font
{}% Indent amount
{\bfseries\color{cadmiumgreen}}% Theorem head font
{}% Punctuation after theorem head
{.5em}% Space after theorem head
{}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)
\theoremstyle{styledef}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\newcommand{\statedefsolid}[2][\textwidth]{
  \par\noindent\tikzstyle{mybox} = [fill=yellow!20,
   thick,rectangle,inner sep=6pt,path picture={\fill [green!50!black] ([xshift=-6.15cm]path picture bounding box.north) rectangle (path picture bounding box.south west);}]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}{#2}\end{minipage}
   };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\statetheoremsolid}[2][\textwidth]{
  \par\noindent\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=amber,fill=gray!17,
   thick,rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=6pt]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}{#2}\end{minipage}
   };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\statedefsolid{
\begin{definition}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec est venenatis, maximus purus eu, ultrices justo. Integer ac mattis lectus. Praesent luctus lectus orci, vitae congue elit tempus vitae. Maecenas accumsan aliquet gravida. Maecenas vitae quam et lectus imperdiet feugiat. Sed sodales ipsum a dolor lobortis pretium. Sed at ipsum ac ante sollicitudin vehicula tempus a arcu. Integer volutpat malesuada nibh, at laoreet leo maximus non. Nulla vitae pulvinar erat.
\end{definition} 
}

\statetheoremsolid{
\begin{thm}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec est venenatis, maximus purus eu, ultrices justo. Integer ac mattis lectus. Praesent luctus lectus orci, vitae congue elit tempus vitae. Maecenas accumsan aliquet gravida. Maecenas vitae quam et lectus imperdiet feugiat. Sed sodales ipsum a dolor lobortis pretium. Sed at ipsum ac ante sollicitudin vehicula tempus a arcu. Integer volutpat malesuada nibh, at laoreet leo maximus non. Nulla vitae pulvinar erat.
\end{thm}
}

\end{document}
```

Edit: To have more control about width of minipage, change both `newcommands`:

```
\newcommand{\statedefsolid}[2]{
  \par\noindent\tikzstyle{mybox} = [fill=yellow!20,
   thick,rectangle,inner sep=6pt,path picture={\fill [green!50!black] ([xshift=-6.15cm]path picture bounding box.north) rectangle (path picture bounding box.south west);}]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}{#2}\end{minipage}
   };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\statetheoremsolid}[2]{
  \par\noindent\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=amber,fill=gray!17,
   thick,rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=6pt]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}{#2}\end{minipage}
   };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

And now, the command in def/theorem text will need more one parameter which control de width of minipage:

```
\statetheoremsolid{0.95\textwidth}{
 \begin{thm}
   ...
 \end{thm}
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Jean Pimenta

Comment: Hi, Dear Pimenta, I used your codes and it looks nice, but the boxes overflow a little  on the right side. How can I adjust them? Thanks.