# The Definition and Theorem boxes are a little overflow on the right side, How can I fix them?

Tags: tikz-pgf, newtheorem

I used the [codes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521148/how-can-i-get-the-definition-and-theorem-environment-like-these-in-latex-package) provided by Jean Pimenta. It looks nice but the  Definition and Theorem boxes are a little overflowed on the right side. How can I fix them?

[image]

Comment: I recommend using `tcolorbox` for this. It supports boxed theorems out of the box. (Many boxes, I know. ;-)

Comment: Thank you @ Schrödinger's cat. Would you like to provide me a code template? many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At `\newcommand{\statetheoremsolid}[2][\textwidth]`, I put to be textwidth. You have two choices to modificate this:

1. Change this `[\textwidth]` to `[0.95\textwidth]`, for example. Or other number that is better for you.
2. Delete this `[\textwidth]` --> `\newcommand{\statetheoremsolid}[2]`. Where you put your theorem you will need the command `\statetheoremsolid{0.95\textwidth}{ ... }`.

Choosing the second:

```
\newcommand{\statedefsolid}[2]{
  \par\noindent\tikzstyle{mybox} = [fill=yellow!20,
   thick,rectangle,inner sep=6pt,path picture={\fill [green!50!black] ([xshift=-6.15cm]path picture bounding box.north) rectangle (path picture bounding box.south west);}]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
   \node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}{#2}\end{minipage}
   };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\statetheoremsolid}[2]{
  \par\noindent\tikzstyle{mybox} = [draw=amber,fill=gray!17,
   thick,rectangle,rounded corners,inner sep=6pt]
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [mybox] (box){%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}{#2}\end{minipage}
   };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Now, both `\statetheoremsolid` and `\statedefsolid` needs two parameters; the first will be the width of minipage.

Comment: Many thanks! It looks nice now.